# List of supported languages from theMovieDB API

Tags: themoviedb-api

I am using TheMovieDB API for getting information about several movies. The API supports usage of different languages.

https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

I am aware that the API has a function to get the current language being set.

Is there any way to get the list of all supported languages?

In my app, I am planning to add a option for the users to select their desired language to see the movie details in their language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to get all the supported languages list from the API. The API docs does not have any information on that.

I am closing this questions, as other might look for a solution on this.

If I am wrong, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/movies/movieidtranslations
Hope it will be usefull

Answer (score 1):

You can get the official list of supported languages from this endpoint:

https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/configuration/get-primary-translations

As of today the endpoint returns the following ISO codes:

```
  "ar-AE",
  "ar-SA",
  "bg-BG",
  "bn-BD",
  "ca-ES",
  "ch-GU",
  "cs-CZ",
  "da-DK",
  "de-DE",
  "el-GR",
  "en-US",
  "eo-EO",
  "es-ES",
  "es-MX",
  "eu-ES",
  "fa-IR",
  "fi-FI",
  "fr-CA",
  "fr-FR",
  "he-IL",
  "hi-IN",
  "hu-HU",
  "id-ID",
  "it-IT",
  "ja-JP",
  "ka-GE",
  "kn-IN",
  "ko-KR",
  "lt-LT",
  "ml-IN",
  "nb-NO",
  "nl-NL",
  "no-NO",
  "pl-PL",
  "pt-BR",
  "pt-PT",
  "ro-RO",
  "ru-RU",
  "sk-SK",
  "sl-SI",
  "sr-RS",
  "sv-SE",
  "ta-IN",
  "te-IN",
  "th-TH",
  "tr-TR",
  "uk-UA",
  "vi-VN",
  "zh-CN",
  "zh-TW"
```

I tested some of the languages with the genres endpoint:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list

Some of them return `null` for the genre names (meaning they have not been translated).

You can see an overview of the translated material at https://www.themoviedb.org/contribute.

Answer (score 1):

This url shows a way that api works for different languages but it doesn't say which languages are supported.

https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/languages

The supported languages are listed in this link:
https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/configuration/get-languages

Notice that some languages exist but the whole details are not translated and some parts like the overview or sometimes the title is translated. I wish I could help. (don't forget to put your api key in the urls both links tells you)

Answer (score 0):

It is specified by ISO code 639-1: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1

I found this in the java-API for TMDB
https://github.com/holgerbrandl/themoviedbapi/blob/master/src/main/java/info/movito/themoviedbapi/model/Discover.java#L69

[List of ISO Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)